# Comparing parallel k-means batch vs mini-batch speed

Tags: scikit-learn

I am trying to cluster 1000 dimension, 250k vectors using k-means. The machine that I am working on has 80 dual-cores.

Just confirming, if anyone has compared the run-time of k-means default batch parallel version against k-means mini-batch version? The [example comparison page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_mini_batch_kmeans.html#example-cluster-plot-mini-batch-kmeans-py) on sklean documents doesn't provide much info as the dataset is quite small.

Much appreciate your help.

Regards,

Comment: I am working with both of them for different parameters to see which performs better. But I still posted the question here to cross-check if someone has already done this before. I will share my results too.

Comment: What was your conclusion?

Answer (score 2):

[Conventional wisdom](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/) holds that `Mini-Batch K-Means` should be faster and more efficient for greater than 10,000 samples.  Since you have 250,000 samples, you should probably use mini-batch if you don't want to test it out on your own.

Note that the [example you referenced](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_mini_batch_kmeans.html#example-cluster-plot-mini-batch-kmeans-py) can very easily be changed to a 5000, 10,000 or 20,000 point example by changing n_samples in this line:

```
X, labels_true = make_blobs(n_samples=3000, centers=centers, cluster_std=0.7)
```

I agree that this won't necessarily scale the same for 1000 dimensional vectors, but since you are constructing the example and are using either `k-means` or `mini batch k-means` and it only takes a second to switch between them... You should just do a scaling study for your 1000 dimensional vectors for 5k, 10k, 15k, 20k samples.

Theoretically, there is no reason why `Mini-Batch K-Means` should underperform `K-Means` due to vector dimensionality and we know that it does better for larger sample sizes, so I would go with mini batch off the cuff e.g. bias for action over research.

Comment: Thanks AN6U5 for you response. What I am looking for is the comparison between "parallel" version of k-means batch (by employing n_jobs arg) against mini-batch.

Comment: I am working with both of them for different parameters to see which performs better. But I still posted the question here to cross-check if someone has already done this before. I will share my results too.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I was not aware that mini batch didn't have a multithreaded implementation.  Yeah, it would be surprising if an 80 core shared memory machine couldn't outperform a single core instance of mini-batch.  I'd be interested to see your strong scaling study results.